# Flutter FormBuilderDropdown deprecated field `allowClear: true`

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

After update Flutter to `3.3.0`, parameter `allowClear: true` is recognised as deprecated:

```
'allowClear' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Please use decoration.suffix to set your desired behaviour.
Try replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement.
```

My Widget looks like this:

```
FormBuilderDropdown(
    onChanged: (value) {
      setState(() {});
    },
    name: 'country',
    decoration: const InputDecoration(
      helperText: 'Country',
    ),
    allowClear: true, // DEPRECATED
    items: items),
```

What is the simplest way to refactor this?

Comment: do you figure out how to fix this?

Comment: In previous version of Flutter You can add `allowClear` as icon on the right edge of widget. Currently it is deprecated, now You can add whatever icon on right edge ane manually realize action under this icon, for example empty this field